# Set spark configuration in aws glue pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, configuration

I am using AWS Glue with pySpark and want to add a couple of configurations in the sparkSession, e.g. `'"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"`,`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable","false"`, `"spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"`, `"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true"`. The code I am using to initialise the context is the following:

```
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session
```

From what I understood from the documentation is that I should add these confs as job parameters when submitting the glue jobs. Is that the case or can they also be added when initializing the spark?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to be erroring out - not sure if it's working

```
hadoop_conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.maxRetries", "20")
hadoop_conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.consistent.retryPolicyType", "exponential")
```

Comment: I confirm that it doesn't update the hadoop config ... confirmed id the Spark UI environment tab

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SparkConf` to configure `spark_session` the glue job:

```py
    #creating SparkConf object
    from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
    conf = SparkConf()

    # Setting configuration in the conf object

    conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")\
        .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")\
        .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse", warehouse_path)\
        .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog")\
        .set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")

    # Passing conf object in the SparkContext object
    
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    
    
    # below spark session will have the above configuration
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```